# Using hive, how can I get the iso week and year at the same time?

Tags: hive

Using hive, how can I  get the iso week and year at the same time?
The function may help get the `weekofyear`,but how to get the correct iso year?

Comment: I have one enginnering method: 
(1) use python to generate two columns of data and save to txt
(2) load the data to hive

Comment: what's your input and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue. Here is a solution:

```
hive> select date_format('2019-01-02', 'Y-ww');
2019-01
hive> select date_format('2018-12-30', 'Y-ww');
2019-01
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that `select date_format('{{ date }}', 'Y-ww');` will always return correct ISO-8601 year-week_of_year value only if the hive server jvm settings use Monday as the first day of week. This may not always be true. Provided `weekofyear` returns correct ISO-8601 week-of-year value the code that works despite of hive server jvm settings is as follows:

```
SELECT concat(cast((
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN month('{{ date }}') = 1 AND weekofyear('{{ date }}') > 50 THEN year('{{ date }}') - 1
    WHEN month('{{ date }}') = 12 AND weekofyear('{{ date }}') = 1 THEN year('{{ date }}') + 1
    ELSE year('{{ date }}')
  END
) AS STRING),'-',lpad(cast(weekofyear('{{ date }}') AS STRING),2,'0')) AS iso_8601_year_week
```